# Textbox in RadGrid changed by client

Tags: telerik, radgrid, radtextbox

Good day,

I have a GridTemplateColumn with a RadTextbox. The textbox values are changed by javascript.  But when i click the textbox,it changes back to its original value.

Please help

**javascript**

```
<title>Untitled Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeCountry() {            

        var grid = $find('<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>');
        var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();            
        var dataItems = MasterTable.get_dataItems();

        var cellCountry = dataItems[0].get_cell("CountryCol");
        var txtCountry = $telerik.$(cellCountry).find('input')[0];
        txtCountry.value = "New Country";        
    }
</script>
```

**.aspx**

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" PageSize="20" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
        <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
        </FilterMenu>
        <ClientSettings>
            <Selecting CellSelectionMode="None" AllowRowSelect="True" />
        </ClientSettings>
        <MasterTableView>
            <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF" />
            <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column" Visible="True">
            </RowIndicatorColumn>
            <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" Visible="True">
            </ExpandCollapseColumn>                               
            <Columns>

                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CR_Branch" HeaderText="Branch"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CR_Country" HeaderText="Branch" Display=false></telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="CR_Country" DataField="CR_Country" UniqueName="CountryCol">
                    <ItemTemplate>                    
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>                                                   
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>                                                

            </Columns>
            <EditFormSettings>
                <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column">
                </EditColumn>
            </EditFormSettings>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridHeaderItem)
    {
    }
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;

        RadTextBox txtCountry = ((RadTextBox)dataItem.FindControl("txtCountry"));
        txtCountry.Text = dataItem["CR_Country"].Text;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Telerik client script **set_value** function rather than pure javascript/HTML, i.e.

```
function changeCountry() {            

    var grid = $find('<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>');
    var MasterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();            
    var dataItems = MasterTable.get_dataItems();

    dataItems[0].findControl("txtCountry").set_value("New Country");
}
```